# HTML5 - Do users get to see all my client code?

Tags: html

If I am building an HTML5 web app.. And all the rendering, UI events, etc are handled on the client, then the client gets to see the source code correct?

I am working on an enterprise HTML5 application but Id like the source code to be hidden. Are there any options?

Is it also possible to somehow hide UI graphic elements (buttons, backgrounds, sounds, etc?)

What are the options here?

Thank you

Comment: Hmmm. Upon further reading on StackOverflow and the web, it seems as though yes, they get to see all the HTML5 and JS code (of course).. Unfortunately most of the interesting, proprietary code in my app will be client side.. The server is really just a relay.. Hmm

Comment: Do I have any options to secure the media perhaps? images, sounds, videos? Hmmm. This may be a deal breaker.. I wonder why this is not a problem for more people. I mean, if developing software for work, this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

My ready answer is No : your javascript code as well as links to jQuery UI code is visible on the client's asking to "view the source".

The question is : Is it possible for your code to be applied/run by the client's browser without being shown as "source?"Is there a way :- to prevent the client from seeing the "source"; or - to destroy the incoming code as soon as it has been run and displayed once?
The second eventuality seems excluded unless there are no further javascript actions on the client's side(?)

Danquest

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: No.

Why? Well, your browser (the *client*) effectively *downloads* assets like `HTML`, `JS` and `CSS` (along with images and other media objects), to render on the users machine.

Because all client code is downloaded to the client, the user can essentially do with the client code, whatever they wish to.

Server side code does not get to the client, because it is processed on the server, which then produces client translatable output...again, `HTML` etc. You only see the end result, with the source that produced it locked away on your guarded server.

Your best bet, is to simply minify and compress your `JS` assets. This won't do much against a savvy developer, but it may be off-putting to the casual thief.

In any case, theft is theft and if your code is found to be used by someone else's company, I guess you have a case to file a lawsuit against them...even though in a way, it's public code.

Make sure you put a license statement with all of your code, so that you're legally covered.

Comment: When was the last time you pulled the algorithms out of Google's Map API? It'd have to be pure gold for people to take the time to go through minified JS to pull out the source code.

Comment: Well, I don't think their algorithms are done client side. There may be client side AJAX requests made to an API, but nobody will have access to the code that produces the data sets. In any case, un-minifying code is a trivial task. Just open a minified script in Firebug and click the prettify button.

Comment: It's not a trivial task. Pushing the prettify button does not restore local variable names to what they once where - that information is lost forever upon minification. Pushing the prettify button might make it easier to see **where** the functions are, but not necessarily what they are or what they do.